# Hash Table For Loop - ping IP Address for set Duration

Tags: powershell, loops, for-loop, hash, ping

I am stuck on this little project I've been working on.

My out put is blank, not sure how to call the info right. I keep getting on one line in my excel

`#Output Hash Table as CSV`
`$IPAddressHash.GetEnumerator()`

I also think I have some missing info here...
`$IPAddressHash.Add($IPAddressToPing)`

Thanks in advance

```
#Place holder
$InputText1 = #unused
$InputText2 = "TestSite" ##Popup input box


$DateTime = $(get-date -Format yyyyddmm_hhmmtt)

#Set Output File
$OutputCSVFilePath = "C:\MSP_PingLogs\ $($InputText2) $($DateTime).csv"

#Set Information
$IPAddress = "192.168.0.147"
$SecondsToRun = 5
 
#Hash Table to hold results
$IPAddressHash = @(
   $IPAddress)

$outList = foreach ($IPAddress in $IPAddressToPing){
}

#Test Ping
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $SecondsToRun; $i++){
$Pingable = Test-Connection -ComputerName $IPAddressToPing -Count 1 -Quiet
if ($Pingable)
    {
    Write-Host "Seccess" $($IPAddressToPing) at $(Get-Date), $responseTime -ForegroundColor Green
    #$IPAddressHash.($IPAddressToPing.("IPAddressToPing"),1)
}
else {
    Write-Host "FAILED PING " $($IPAddressToPing) at $(Get-Date), $responseTime -ForegroundColor Red
    #$IPAddressHash.($IPAddressToPing.("IPAddressToPing"),0)
}
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    }


$outList = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Address= $IPAddressToPing
        Date= $DateTime
        Pingable = $Pingable
    }
    )

$outList | Export-Csv -path $OutputCSVFilePath -NoTypeInformation


#Show where file is
Write-Host "Output can be found at: $($OutputCSVFilePath)"
```

Comment: why are you using a hashtable instead of a `[PSCusomtObject]`? ///// also, you are just adding the ip address with no indicator of fail/succeed. ///// also also, please read the docs on how to add to a hashtable ... you are doing it oh-so-very-wrong ... [*grin*]

Comment: Thx @Lee_Dailey, I am not sure I understand PSCusomtObject, I was told by a colleague to use a hash table. 

As far as the fail/succeed, it seems to work with the re and green in PS

Comment: the fail and succeed for each ping target is _only on the screen_. [*grin*] the info in the hashtable is ONLY the ip address. **_also, have you read the instructions on how to add an item to a hashtable yet?_** your code is _doing it wrong_ ...

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, Appreciate the response. I really do. I am diving in to something that I just simple don't understand . May take me years to get it. This is not my work for sure.

Comment: you are quite welcome! please take a look a the Answer i posted. i think it does what you want ... [*grin*]

Comment: you have at least 3 problems with that. [*grin*] **_[1]_** your PSCO starts with `@(` and MUST start with `@{`. **_[2]_** you never define `$responseTime`. **_[3]_** your `$DateTime` never changes, so every line will FALSELY report the time. ///// plus, your datetime stamp is in `hh` with `am/pm` when you really otta use `HH` for 24 hour time. plus plus, you are reporting your times in minutes when the time spans are in seconds.

Comment: You cannot completely change the question **after** someone has answered the original question. Instead, you should have accepted @Lee_Daily s answer and posted a new question.

Answer (score 0):

here is how i would do what i *think* you are trying to do ... [*grin*]

what it does ...

- creates a list of systems to ping
  replace the entire `#region/#endregion` stuff with a `Get-Content` call, or some other way to load your list as plain text system names.
- sets the various constants
- iterates thru the system list
- iterates thru the test count
- gets a `$False/$True` response from `Test-Connection`
- writes the "pingable" info to the screen
- creates a `[PSCustomObject]` with the desired properties
- sends that to the `$Results` collection
- displays the collection on screen
- saves the collection to a CSV file

here's the code ...

```
#region >>> fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$ComputerList = @(
    'LocalHost'
    '10.0.0.1'
    '127.0.0.1'
    'BetterNotBeThere'
    )
#endregion >>> fake reading in a text file

$TestCount = 3
$DateTimeFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ff'
$LogDir = $env:TEMP
$PingLog = 'PingLog_-_{0}.csv' -f (Get-Date).Date.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
$FullPingLog = Join-Path -Path $LogDir -ChildPath $PingLog

$Results = foreach ($CL_Item in $ComputerList)
    {
    foreach ($TC_Item in 1..$TestCount)
        {
        $Pingable = Test-Connection -ComputerName $CL_Item -Count 1 -Quiet
        if ($Pingable)
            {
            Write-Host ('Ping of {0} was successful.' -f $CL_Item) -ForegroundColor 'Green'
            }
            else
            {
            Write-Warning ('    Unable to Ping {0} ...' -f $CL_Item)
            }
        }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName = $CL_Item
        Pingable = $Pingable
        TimeStamp = Get-Date -Format $DateTimeFormat
        }
    }

# show on screen
$Results |
    # this forces things to show immediately
    #    otherwise the "Write-*" calls might interleave with the output stream
    Out-Host

# send to CSV
$Results |
    Export-Csv -LiteralPath $FullPingLog -NoTypeInformation
```

output to screen ...

```
Ping of LocalHost was successful.
Ping of LocalHost was successful.
Ping of LocalHost was successful.
WARNING:     Unable to Ping 10.0.0.1 ...
WARNING:     Unable to Ping 10.0.0.1 ...
WARNING:     Unable to Ping 10.0.0.1 ...
Ping of 127.0.0.1 was successful.
Ping of 127.0.0.1 was successful.
Ping of 127.0.0.1 was successful.
WARNING:     Unable to Ping BetterNotBeThere ...
WARNING:     Unable to Ping BetterNotBeThere ...
WARNING:     Unable to Ping BetterNotBeThere ...

ComputerName     Pingable TimeStamp             
------------     -------- ---------             
LocalHost            True 2020-04-10 19:47:33.98
10.0.0.1            False 2020-04-10 19:47:45.62
127.0.0.1            True 2020-04-10 19:47:45.65
BetterNotBeThere    False 2020-04-10 19:47:45.68
```

content of the `PingLog_-_2020-04-10.csv` file ...

```
"ComputerName","Pingable","TimeStamp"
"LocalHost","True","2020-04-10 19:47:33.98"
"10.0.0.1","False","2020-04-10 19:47:45.62"
"127.0.0.1","True","2020-04-10 19:47:45.65"
"BetterNotBeThere","False","2020-04-10 19:47:45.68"
```

Comment: Thx for the post, used what you said. For this script, it only need test a single IP over and over for a set Duration, in hours. I have it set to Sec's at the moment for testing.  Test count would not work very well. I will have a popup box with this for Hours to run and the desired  IP address. Just FYI. 

Sooo This is what i modified, but it only creates one line of data in the excel or (csv) file.

Comment: I just changed the posted code above if you wouldn't mind looking at it.

Comment: @AlexanderWayne - i will look ... but you need to start making your requirements clear at the start, not after folks have worked on what you _seem_ to be hinting at. [*grin*]